# Apache Ignite indexes using visor

Tags: indexing, ignite

I am using ignite. I want to use query index in cache configuration. I want see the indexes using visor or any other tool. How to set check index in ignite?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [JDBC metadata](https://www.progress.com/blogs/jdbc-tutorial-extracting-database-metadata-via-jdbc-driver) to gain information about secondary indexes.

You can issue `!indexes` command in sqlline shipped with Apache Ignite to do that manually.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried to use !indexes from sqlline .it doen't show indexes from cache configuration. I am using queryentity and queryindex to set indexes on cache configuration. I am using binaryobject to store my data in cache.

Comment: Please provide an example of your cache configuration so that I can check.